# Linked List Inner Class

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am fairly new to Java and I need to make a linked list. I was told that I need to make a class called "Node" to store each element. I've written the class:

```
public class Node()
{
    public T data;
    public Node next;

    public Node(T data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    public T getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

However, I am not allowed to make a separate class, it has to be within the LinkedList class. I understand how to make an inner class of something like an imported iterator, but the "Node" is not imported. How would I do this?

Comment: make the LinkedList class public, but put the Node class inside it (not public).

Comment: Thats what I did, but it gives me the error "Syntax at error on token "class", @ expected.

Comment: But this is exactly the code you need to put above otherwise you're asking us to do your homework.

Comment: please show the exact code that got you this error.

Comment: you probably didn't wrap the inner class in {} brackets.

Comment: package listClasses;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class BasicLinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T>
{
 
 private class Node()
 {
  public T data;
  public Node next;
  
  public Node(T data, Node next)
  {
   this.data = data;
   this.next = next;
  }
  
  public Node getNext()
  {
   return next;
  }
  public T getData()
  {
   return data;
  }
 }

Comment: Im actually the stupidest person alive

Comment: syntax issues aside, you may find this helpful https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Thanks and sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Linked{
     class Node{
        int value;
        Node next;
        Node(int data,Node next){
          value=data;
          this.next=next;
        }
        Node getNext(){
         return next;}
        }

//Rest of the linked list methods
}
```

This is called an inner class which is nothing but a class nested inside another class. When we know that a class has no existence outside the main class we nest that class inside the main class i.e as we know that this node class cannot be used outside anywhere in the program thus we made this class an inner class.